# Black Screen After A Reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, freeze, black-screen-of-death

## Info

After a normal Windows 10 reboot, nothing appeared on the screen.
I had the problem for quite some time but usually after unplugging and replugging the PC the screen would work and everything was fine.
Not sure what was causing the problem I thought that this was just a one-time thing.
This PC is my test server, that is running 24/7 so usually, I don't turn it off or reboot.

## The Problem

When I do a restart on the pc or shut it down the next time that I want to turn it back on the screen will be black "no signal".
nothing will appear on the screen, the PC is working just no video signal.
I can move the mouse and to functions because the keyboard is working.
Remoting to the PC also doesn't work because the PC is offline.
The Monitor and cable are working because sometimes the PC boots up with no problems.
Now here ware the problems get bizarre:
after "take it out and in" the pc sometimes would boot normally.
also sometimes after waiting for 24H the pc would boot up fine with no problems.\

## The Luck Ran Out

This problem has been dragging on for a couple of months now... and I think that my PC gave up.

### What I did To Solve It

- Chek The Cables
- Check the Connection
- Start with GPU
- Chek The Screen
- Clean Everyting
- start with no GPU(intgrted grufics)
- CMOS battery out(take it out wate 3 - 2 minuits)
- BIOS resat
- complitly turn off and turn it on

### PC Info

```
Summary
     Operating System
         More data is available.
     CPU
         AMD Ryzen 5 33 °C
         Picasso 12nm Technology
     RAM
         16.0GB Dual-Channel Unknown @ 1330MHz (20-19-19-43)
     Motherboard
         ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. PRIME B450M-A (AM4)   33 °C
     Graphics
         2460G4 (1920x1080@120Hz)
         8176MB ATI Radeon RX 5500 XT (ASUStek Computer Inc)
         2048MB ATI AMD Radeon RX Vega 11 Graphics (ASUStek Computer Inc)
         CrossFire Disabled
     Storage
         447GB SanDisk SSD PLUS 480GB (SATA (SSD))   31 °C
         1863GB TOSHIBA HDWD120 (SATA )  38 °C
     Optical Drives
         No optical disk drives detected
     Audio
         USB Audio Device
Operating System
 More data is available.
CPU
     AMD Ryzen 5
         Cores   4
         Threads 8
         Name    AMD Ryzen 5
         Code Name   Picasso
         Package Socket AM4 (1331)
         Technology  12nm
         Specification   AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
         Family  F
         Extended Family 17
         Model   8
         Extended Model  18
         Stepping    1
         Instructions    MMX (+), SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, SSE4A, AMD 64, NX, VMX, AES, AVX, AVX2, FMA3
         Virtualization  Supported, Enabled
         Hyperthreading  Supported, Enabled
         Fan Speed   901 RPM
         Bus Speed   99.8 MHz
         Average Temperature 33 °C
             Caches
                 L1 Data Cache Size  4 x 32 KBytes
                 L1 Instructions Cache Size  4 x 64 KBytes
                 L2 Unified Cache Size   4 x 512 KBytes
                 L3 Unified Cache Size   4096 KBytes
             Cores
                     Core 0
                         Core Speed  1363.9 MHz
                         Multiplier  x 13.67
                         Bus Speed   99.8 MHz
                         Temperature 33 °C
                         Threads APIC ID: 0, 1
                     Core 1
                         Core Speed  1363.9 MHz
                         Multiplier  x 13.67
                         Bus Speed   99.8 MHz
                         Threads APIC ID: 2, 3
                     Core 2
                         Core Speed  1363.9 MHz
                         Multiplier  x 13.67
                         Bus Speed   99.8 MHz
                         Threads APIC ID: 4, 5
                     Core 3
                         Core Speed  3068.8 MHz
                         Multiplier  x 30.75
                         Bus Speed   99.8 MHz
                         Threads APIC ID: 6, 7
RAM
     Memory slots
         Total memory slots  4
         Used memory slots   2
         Free memory slots   2
     Memory
         Type    Unknown
         Size    16384 MBytes
         Channels #  Dual
         DRAM Frequency  1330.6 MHz
         CAS# Latency (CL)   20 clocks
         RAS# to CAS# Delay (tRCD)   19 clocks
         RAS# Precharge (tRP)    19 clocks
         Cycle Time (tRAS)   43 clocks
         Bank Cycle Time (tRC)   62 clocks
         Command Rate (CR)   1T
     Physical Memory
         Memory Usage    21 %
         Total Physical  13 GB
         Available Physical  10 GB
         Total Virtual   33 GB
         Available Virtual   28 GB
     SPD
         Number Of SPD Modules   2
             Slot #1
                 Type    Unknown
                 Size    8192 MBytes
                 Manufacturer    Crucial Technology
                 Max Bandwidth   DDR4-2666 (1333 MHz)
                 Part Number CT8G4DFS8266.M8FD
                 Serial Number   631700839
                 Week/year   52 / 19
                     Timing table
                             JEDEC #1
                                 Frequency   701.8 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    10.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    10
                                 RAS# Precharge  10
                                 tRAS    23
                                 tRC 33
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #2
                                 Frequency   842.1 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    12.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    12
                                 RAS# Precharge  12
                                 tRAS    27
                                 tRC 39
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #3
                                 Frequency   912.3 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    13.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    13
                                 RAS# Precharge  13
                                 tRAS    30
                                 tRC 43
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #4
                                 Frequency   982.5 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    14.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    14
                                 RAS# Precharge  14
                                 tRAS    32
                                 tRC 46
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #5
                                 Frequency   1052.6 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    15.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    15
                                 RAS# Precharge  15
                                 tRAS    34
                                 tRC 49
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #6
                                 Frequency   1122.8 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    16.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    16
                                 RAS# Precharge  16
                                 tRAS    36
                                 tRC 52
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #7
                                 Frequency   1193.0 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    17.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    17
                                 RAS# Precharge  17
                                 tRAS    39
                                 tRC 56
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #8
                                 Frequency   1263.2 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    18.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    18
                                 RAS# Precharge  18
                                 tRAS    41
                                 tRC 59
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #9
                                 Frequency   1333.3 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    19.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    19
                                 RAS# Precharge  19
                                 tRAS    43
                                 tRC 62
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #10
                                 Frequency   1333.3 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    20.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    19
                                 RAS# Precharge  19
                                 tRAS    43
                                 tRC 62
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
             Slot #2
                 Type    Unknown
                 Size    8192 MBytes
                 Manufacturer    Crucial Technology
                 Max Bandwidth   DDR4-2666 (1333 MHz)
                 Part Number CT8G4DFS8266.M8FD
                 Serial Number   622109428
                 Week/year   47 / 19
                     Timing table
                             JEDEC #1
                                 Frequency   701.8 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    10.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    10
                                 RAS# Precharge  10
                                 tRAS    23
                                 tRC 33
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #2
                                 Frequency   842.1 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    12.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    12
                                 RAS# Precharge  12
                                 tRAS    27
                                 tRC 39
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #3
                                 Frequency   912.3 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    13.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    13
                                 RAS# Precharge  13
                                 tRAS    30
                                 tRC 43
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #4
                                 Frequency   982.5 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    14.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    14
                                 RAS# Precharge  14
                                 tRAS    32
                                 tRC 46
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #5
                                 Frequency   1052.6 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    15.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    15
                                 RAS# Precharge  15
                                 tRAS    34
                                 tRC 49
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #6
                                 Frequency   1122.8 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    16.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    16
                                 RAS# Precharge  16
                                 tRAS    36
                                 tRC 52
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #7
                                 Frequency   1193.0 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    17.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    17
                                 RAS# Precharge  17
                                 tRAS    39
                                 tRC 56
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #8
                                 Frequency   1263.2 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    18.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    18
                                 RAS# Precharge  18
                                 tRAS    41
                                 tRC 59
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #9
                                 Frequency   1333.3 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    19.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    19
                                 RAS# Precharge  19
                                 tRAS    43
                                 tRC 62
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
                             JEDEC #10
                                 Frequency   1333.3 MHz
                                 CAS# Latency    20.0
                                 RAS# To CAS#    19
                                 RAS# Precharge  19
                                 tRAS    43
                                 tRC 62
                                 Voltage 1.200 V
Motherboard
 Manufacturer    ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
 Model   PRIME B450M-A (AM4)
 Version Rev X.0x
 Chipset Vendor  AMD
 Chipset Model   Ryzen SOC
 Chipset Revision    00
 Southbridge Vendor  AMD
 Southbridge Model   B450
 Southbridge Revision    51
 System Temperature  33 °C
     BIOS
         Brand   American Megatrends Inc.
         Version 1823
         Date    10/15/2019
     Voltage
         CPU CORE    0.981 V
         MEMORY CONTROLLER   2.529 V
         VIN2    2.071 V
         VIN3    2.027 V
         VIN4    2.027 V
         VIN5    1.940 V
         VIN6    2.027 V
         VIN7    1.679 V
     PCI Data
             Slot PCI-E
                 Slot Type   PCI-E
                 Slot Usage  In Use
                 Data lanes  x8
                 Slot Designation    PCIEX16
                 Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                 Slot Number 0
             Slot PCI-E
                 Slot Type   PCI-E
                 Slot Usage  Available
                 Data lanes  x1
                 Slot Designation    PCIEX1_1
                 Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                 Slot Number 1
             Slot PCI-E
                 Slot Type   PCI-E
                 Slot Usage  Available
                 Data lanes  x1
                 Slot Designation    PCIEX1_2
                 Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                 Slot Number 2
Graphics
     Monitor
         Name    2460G4 on AMD 15D8:C8
         Current Resolution  1920x1080 pixels
         Work Resolution 1920x1040 pixels
         State   Enabled, Primary, Unsafe
         Monitor Width   1920
         Monitor Height  1080
         Monitor BPP 32 bits per pixel
         Monitor Frequency   120 Hz
         Device  \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0
     ATI Radeon RX 5500 XT
         Manufacturer    ATI
         Model   Radeon RX 5500 XT
         Device ID   1002-7340
         Revision    C6
         Subvendor   ASUStek Computer Inc (1043)
         Current Performance Level   Level 0
         Current GPU Clock   0 MHz
         Current Memory Clock    4 MHz
         Current Shader Clock    4 MHz
         Technology  7 nm
         GPU Clock   0.0 (1733.0) MHz
         Crossfire   Disabled
         Driver version  30.0.14011.3017
         BIOS Version    115-D332P20-100
         Memory Type GDDR6
         Memory  8176 MB
         Bandwidth   224.0 GB/s
             Count of performance levels : 1
                     Level 1 - "Perf Level 0"
                         Memory Clock    26 MHz
                         Shader Clock    16 MHz
     ATI AMD Radeon(TM) RX Vega 11 Graphics
         Manufacturer    ATI
         Model   AMD Radeon RX Vega 11 Graphics
         Device ID   1002-15D8
         Revision    C9
         Subvendor   ASUStek Computer Inc (1043)
         Current Performance Level   Level 0
         Current GPU Clock   200 MHz
         Current Memory Clock    1333 MHz
         Current Shader Clock    1333 MHz
         GPU Clock   1400.0 MHz
         Core Voltage    0.001 V
         Crossfire   Disabled
         Driver version  30.0.14011.3017
         BIOS Version    113-PICASSO-114
         Memory Type DDR4
         Memory  2048 MB
         Bandwidth   42.7 GB/s
             Count of performance levels : 8
                 Level 1 - "Perf Level 0"
                 Level 2 - "Perf Level 1"
                 Level 3 - "Perf Level 2"
                 Level 4 - "Perf Level 3"
                 Level 5 - "Perf Level 4"
                 Level 6 - "Perf Level 5"
                 Level 7 - "Perf Level 6"
                 Level 8 - "Perf Level 7"
```

#### Update 4/17/2021

The Problem Might Be The Motherboard HDMI Connection, I bought different cables to try and the HDMI port might be faulty.
Lucky for me I'm Under Warranty... But is strange that the port only failed after a reboot. might be another issue causing this problem.
I suspect that this is a Driver's Issue

#### Update 4/19/2021

Motherboard Problems... After Testing It Seems to be a motherboard problem the HDMI Port contacts aren't working...
The GPU and PSU are working as they should.

Comment: If you're getting the same problem with different gpus, the problem is likely a hardware fault with some other component. Did you try a different screen? CPU? Power supply?

Comment: All the hardware is good, I used the CPU 1 day ago... and the PSU works with bo problems. All the hardware in the pc is working./ The problem is that sometimes the pc just wouldn't show anything on the screen

Comment: Are you getting a black screen or a no video signal screen _(these are two different things - the former would signal a likely GPU driver issue, the latter a hardware issue)_? No signal would be accompanied by a monitor message stating something to the effect of No Signal

Comment: @JW0914
This is A motherboard problem because all the parts are working on another pc fine no problems

Comment: @thefourCraft HDMI ports are relatively hard to damage, unless a cable was accidentally tugged on with significant force at the wrong angle or over time from an unsupported beefy cable _(in case a beefy cable is being used, [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/category/cables/hdmi-cables/hdmi-cables??nav=1&keyword=&v_HDR_uFilter=Yes&v_HDR_uFilter=Dynamic%20HDR) makes [slim](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=24187) 4K/8K cables and all cables they manufacture are lifetime warrantied)_. This isn't to imply it's not the HDMI port, simply things to be aware of if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Following you could try:

- remove all RAM sticks but one (also reseat the one), maybe one is faulty or has lost concact
- look for information your machine can give you (motherboard speaker, debug leds etc.)
- remove everything attached that is not needed for a screen signal (drives, expansion cards etc.)
- reset the bios (set jumper accordingly or remove motherboard battery and wait a minute with no power to the machine)

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment

Comment: @Marin Althuis
This was a motherboard issue, the HDMI port is damaged I think.